# How tensions of $y$ axis are different, but overall tension still the same?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, waves, string

Let's say rope is at equilibrium and both ends are attached to something(boxes). We put a finger on it and let go. So it starts accelerating upwards.

Let's consider just a tiny, tiny piece of the string. Each end has a tension tugging on it from the rest of the string. Those tensions are the same because tension is uniform throughout the string. But the components are not the same.

It's easy to see tensions on y axis on these 2 ends would be different, since it accelerates vertically, but how about tensions on x axis ?

Tensions on the x axis on these ends must be the same, otherwise we would get a net force, causing it to accelerate right or left which is not the case here.

So I'm wondering if y components are different, and x components the same, how do we conclude overal tensions on these ends are the same ? due to `y` difference, overal tensions have to be different as well.

**For your information, I arrived at this question as I'm learning the derivation of the classical wave equation. So this might help you understand better how to answer**.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to dig deeper into the underlying assumptions in the derivation you are looking at, but taking a stab at it...

The string must extend/shrink as it oscillates, since the length of the curve changes as the string oscillates. Therefore, we can still have unequal x components without a horizontal acceleration. Of course you might argue that then the linear mass density would change, but you have to pick how you are going to idealize the system in order to make a model of it.

Comment: It seems like the overall tension on both ends of the tiny piece of the string are not equal to each other. I saw the derivation again and they take deflections on x-direction small/negligible so T1x = T2x. Though T1y != T2y. If both true, T1 != T2, but in another source, they say overall tension is the same as it's uniform. Really. funny. In my opinion, I think T1 != T2. do you agree ?

Answer (score 0):

To derive the wave equation a number of assumptions are made.
One could then compare predictions from the derived equation with experimental data.

One assumption is to ignore the effects of the gravitational forces and air resistance acting on the rope.

The rope and its characteristics are the next thing to look at.

One assumes that the rope has mass and so has a mass per unit length.
So what happens when the rope is stretched?
The assumption is made that compared with the length of the rope the extension of the rope is very small and so its mass per unit length stays constant.
Similarly one assumes that with the small extension the tension, $T$, in the rope stays constant.

Consider a small section of the rope $AB$ as shown in the left-hand diagram below.

[image]

The force diagram is shown on the left.
You will note that the restoring force $T'$ is not vertical so it does have a component to the right.
The assumption is made that if $\Delta \theta$ is very small and thus the component of restoring force to the right is very much smaller than the vertical component and so can be neglected.

Thus the derivation you have been shown is only an approximation to what happens in the real world but for a lot of purposed is "good enough".

Reducing the number of assumptions produces a more complex wave equation.
As an example in this paper, [Enhanced wave-based modelling of musical strings. Part 1: Plucked strings](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/83938784.pdf) you might note is that the wave equation which is used, **(2)** in the paper, has an extra term in it, $EI\dfrac{\partial^4y}{\partial^4x}$, which is to do with the elastic properties and shape/size of a string.

Comment: Ok, So, I understand why T1x = T2x.  I also understand why T1y != T2y.  These two seem good to me. but then in one video, author says T1 = T2 which seems wrong to me. hence my question. WDYT ?

Comment: The tension on either side of the element is assumed to be the same, it is the x and y components of the tension which differ at each end of the element.

Comment: Well, we assume `x` components are the same and `y` components different. How would this get us same tension on both ends ?

Comment: The x components are not the same but the difference between them is much less than the difference between the y components.  This means that the net force is approximately vertical, ie we can ignore the horizontal force.

Comment: I understand that but the derivation they start with is T1cosA = T2cosB and due to small angle, cosA = cosB. Hence T1 = T2. but since T1y != T2y, how T1 = T2 ? seems like a contradiction